# SharePoint 2010 documents not showing up in document library search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site with some document libraries. I've found that some of the Word documents in a couple of libraries will not show up in search results that are conducted *within* their respective libraries.

So, searching in document library "Resource Docs" for document XYZ will yield no results. However, using the search webpart on the main SharePoint home page (that searches ALL document libraries) *will* return document XYZ in the search results!

I've verified that the documents that are affected (ie- missing from document library searches) *are* being crawled, as they appear in the crawl log.

Also I checked to see that they were published (they are) and I even set the "Who should see draft items in this document library?" option in the Document Library settings to "Any user who can read items."

In addition, I've verified that missing documents have the same security settings as the parent library (and the other documents that *do* show up in a document library search). I would think that if the crawler account could not hit them they would be absent from the crawler log anyway, and they do appear there as being successfully crawled.

So I'm stumped. There is nothing I can see that is special about these documents that would explain why they are missing from document library searches.

Comment: I discovered that the issue with this was with my zone mappings:

"If you can see your items in advanced search but not in default simple search, this might be the webapp zone setting bug described in MSDN discussion board we identified during testing. If you have multiple zones setup for the same webapp. Please mask sure the default zone is Intranet NOT other settings. This seems to be a bug you could not get search result if the default zone is NOT Intranet."

Our web application zone settings had the intranet site (non-FQDN) not as the Default, and changing it around fixed the issue.